# How to restrict lightsail cdn origin?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have set up a lightsail wordpress instance, static IP and a CDN. I have enabled end to end SSL. Everything works fine except my static IP is still exposed to internet and serves http. How can I block/restrict access to my static IP and allow traffic only through CDN?

I tried searching in AWS docs but could not find any resource.

Comment: You can't. If you block IP address, no one will be able to access your website.

Comment: @Marcin This is not good for SEO because the pages would be indexed by IP address as well. Is there some way of controlling who can access through headers?

Comment: Yes, but not sure you can do this through CDN or you have to do it on your instance using nginx for example.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this issue by adding my domain name in `/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-config.php`

First, I followed instructions in https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/use-single-domain/

**It still did not work.**

Then, I simply changed

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

to

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com');
```

This makes sure that the wordpress siteurl is not dynamic and always redirects to the domain name.

Apparently, this has nothing to do with AWS Lightsail/ CDN.